# How to break an infinite loop

Tags: java, while-loop

this is my piece of code:

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);

            ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            while(sending)
            {
                Statistics statsData = setStatisticsData();
                ous.writeObject(statsData);

                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }           
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException uhe) 
        {
            uhe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

it's the client.it'll sending in an infinite loop an object Statistics. I would implement a way to break this infinite loop through input (es. press a button in the keyboard).ok can I do?how can i break an infinite loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a separate thread:

```
Thread statisticsSendingThread = ...
```

Then simply interrupt it:

```
statisticsSendingThread.interrupt();
```

`InterruptedException` will be thrown, escaping from the loop.

I see you already have a boolean `sending` flag. It will work as well, but with 5 second delay in worst case. Also make sure it is `volatile` - or better, use `isInterrupted()` method of thread. But interrupting the thread using `interrupt()` is by far the easiest way (no extra coding required). And your loop can be truly infinite (<del>`while(true)`</del> although with `while(!isInterrupted())`).

---

BTW your `setStatisticsData()` should probably be named `getStatisticsData()`.

Comment: Another advantage of using `interrupt()` is that it will interrupt `sleep`, `wait` and various other higher-level blocking calls.  You can't achieve that neatly with a custom "have we been killed" flag

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz but Where I should interrupted the thread?

Comment: @user1508419 - In whatever thread reads the keystroke event or character from the keyboard.

Comment: You should still use .isInterrupted() as your loop condition.  If you're in the middle of the writeObject() method, the thread interrupt will not do anything except set the interrupted flag on the current thread.  This is true in general for all blocking io (anything in java.io package).  Only certain methods like Thread.sleep() will actually respond to an interrupt and throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do them on separate threads, and since you are looking for user input it would probably be best to move your code to some asynchronous thread, then simply on input set your `sending` bool to false or interrupt the thread `YourThread.interrupt();`

Answer (score -1):

```
while(sending) 
{ 
    Statistics statsData = setStatisticsData(); 
    ous.writeObject(statsData); 
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    if(EXIT_FLAG == true)
       sending = false;
}
```

EXIT_FLAG can be a static variable that can be updated from outside. You may also want to run this infinite loop in a separate Thread. Read more about how to share data between Threads.

Comment: `if(EXIT_FLAG) break;`? And why do you name variable using capital case? Not my downvote though.

Comment: "You may also want to run this infinite loop in a separate Thread." How is EXIT_FLAG going to be set if not on separate thread?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz - For better readability. Why Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR is caps? I don't know why the down-vote. But interrupting a Thread is not the solution for this. There has a to be a clean way to come out of the loop.

Comment: @NominSim - "You may also want to" implicitly says "you would want to". It's just a way of putting it.

Comment: Not to be picky, but "you may also want to" implies that you either can or can't, but to get the result the OP is looking for it is actually "you have to", there is no choice if he wants results.